# Java Servlet HTTP Status Code 404

Tags: java, servlets

I was having some problem when trying to test the method inside servlet. Here is how I store my servlet class:

[image]

And then when I right click on TrackNYPServlet and run on server, my browser popped out with this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/TrackNYP/servlet/servlet.TrackNYPServlet
```

and also together with error message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /TrackNYP/servlet/servlet.TrackNYPServlet
```

Inside my serlvet class:

```
@WebServlet("/TrackNYPServlet")
public class TrackNYPServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
```

I wonder which part went wrong. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove "servlet." from your url.

Comment: But I thought if the servlet class is under certain package, it should be PackageName.servletClassName?

Comment: No you dont need package.

Comment: See details in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this URL instead?

```
http://localhost:8080/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet
```

This should work.

Comment: No, because you use the URL specified by the @WebServlet annotation. http://hostname:port/app/servletmapping

Answer (score 0):

Url doesn't need package name. It should only contain the path that you defined with `@WebServlet("/TrackNYPServlet")`. So your url should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/TrackNYP/TrackNYPServlet
```

Its like:

```
http - the protocol that you are using
localhost - host where your web server is hosted.
8080 - port where you hosted your webserver on
TrackNYP - Webapp name
TrackNYPServlet - Path which you defined in your custom code.
```